# Algorithm for surface mesh of convex decomposition

Tags: polygons, convex-hull

I have an object mesh. This is loaded into a physics simulator, which does a convex decomposition. Now I want to perform operations outside the simulator that require a mesh representation. I could use the original object mesh but in many cases the convex decomposition is quite rough (the difference between object mesh and simulated shape is significant) but I need to work with the same shape as the simulator.

Concretely, I have a list of vertices, and polygons (consisting of planes and indices into the vertices list) for each of the n convex bodies.

To get the surface of the union of the convex bodies, I assume I will have to check for each vertex if it is inside a polygon of the other bodies and create triangles for the resulting mesh accordingly.

But when actually writing code, it is difficult to decide if these points are on the surface or are inside, and therefore, the triangles should be discarded. Is there a clever way to implement this?

[image]

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost in inferring what you are trying to do.  Can you give a self-contained statement of the problem you want an algorithm for?  Are you looking for a point-in-polygon test?

Comment: Hi, I want an algorithm that takes in a set of convex hulls and returns a triangle mesh of the union of the input hulls.